# My implementation of merge sort is not working

Tags: java, recursion, mergesort

This implementation of merge sort algorithm fails because an ArrayIndexIsOut of bounds.

```
public static int[] mergeSort(int[] toBeSorted) {
    //If there is only one item in the array, and it is said to be sorted
    if (toBeSorted.length <= 1){
        return toBeSorted;
    }

    //find the indexes of the two sub-groups
    int[] left = new int[toBeSorted.length/2];
    int[] right = new int[toBeSorted.length-left.length];
    //Fill each sub-group with the correct numbers
    //Starting with the left group
    for(int i = 0; i <= left.length - 1; i++){
        left[i] = toBeSorted[i];
    }
    //Then the right group
    for(int i = left.length - 1; i <= toBeSorted.length - 1; i++){
        right[i] = toBeSorted[i];
    }


    //Merge sort each sub-group
    mergeSort(left);
    mergeSort(right);

    //Merge the two sub-groups
    toBeSorted = merge(left, right);

    return toBeSorted;
}

//Merging method
public static int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right){
    //Answer array
    int[] merged = new int[left.length + right.length];
    //Next index to check in each array
    int lCursor = 0;
    int rCursor = 0;
    //Next index to place numbers into answer
    int mergedCursor = 0; 

    //The merging part:
    //If there are still items to merge, then do so
    while(mergedCursor != merged.length){
        //left index is empty
        if(lCursor == left.length) {
            merged[mergedCursor] = right[rCursor];
            //increment the correct cursors
            rCursor += 1;
            mergedCursor += 1;
        }
        //right index is empty
        else if(rCursor == right.length) {
            merged[mergedCursor] = right[lCursor];
            //increment the correct cursors
            lCursor += 1;
            mergedCursor += 1;
        } 
        //Left side is smaller
        else if(left[lCursor]<right[rCursor]){
            merged[mergedCursor] = left[lCursor];
            //increment the correct cursors
            lCursor += 1;
            mergedCursor +=1;
        }
        //Right side is smaller
        else if(right[rCursor]<left[lCursor]){
            merged[mergedCursor] = right[rCursor];
            //increment the correct cursors
            rCursor += 1;
            mergedCursor +=1;
        }
    }
    //return the merged output
    return merged;
}
```

The line inside the for loop assigning numbers to the right array is where the problem is, but I can't tell why.
Also, originally I had `i = left.length` in that `for` loop, but that was causing the entire right array to be set to zeros.

EDIT: I changed the second for loop to this:

```
  for(int i = 0; i <= right.length - 1; i++){
        right[i] = toBeSorted[i + left.length];
    }
```

Now the right array is being filled up correctly.

EDIT 2: I fixed the Merging part. For some weird reason when an index was found to be empty, I still took from the empty array. I also changed it to an enhanced for loop to get rid of mergedCursor. The new merging method is as follows:

```
    public static int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right){
    //Answer array
    int[] merged = new int[left.length + right.length];
    //Next index to check in each array
    int lCursor = 0;
    int rCursor = 0;


    //The merging part:
    //Keep going until output array is full
    for (int i = 0; i <= merged.length - 1; i++) {
        //left index is empty
        if(lCursor == left.length) {
            merged[i] = right[rCursor];
            //increment the correct cursor
            rCursor += 1;
        }
        //right index is empty
        else if(rCursor == right.length) {
            merged[i] = left[lCursor];
            //increment the correct cursor
            lCursor += 1;
        } 
        //Left side is smaller
        else if(left[lCursor]<right[rCursor]){
            merged[i] = left[lCursor];
            //increment the correct cursor
            lCursor += 1;
        }
        //Right side is smaller
        else if(right[rCursor]<left[lCursor]){
            merged[i] = right[rCursor];
            //increment the correct cursor
            rCursor += 1;
        }
    }
    //return the merged output
    return merged;
}
```

Comment: `mergeSort` returns a new array (created in `merge`) but in it you call it on left and right and just discard the result.

Comment: That does not fix the problem of the array index being out of bounds the first time through.

Comment: `right[lCursor]` looks odd too. You don't have an IDE you can debug with?

Answer (score 1):

In 2nd for loop, you are starting (i) with (left.Length - 1). What you want is

```
for (int i = right.Length, j = 0; (j <= right.Length - 1) && (i <= toBeSorted.Length - 1); i++, j++)
{
    right[j] = toBeSorted[i];
}
```

Also, the value (left.Length - 1) at which you end your first loop is the same value at which you are starting the next loop. This means that you get the middle value in both(left and right) arrays. But this might not be what you want. So I have changed it to just (right.Length) instead of (right.Length - 1).

Comment: I changed the second For loop to work correctly, but not in the way you suggested. By placing `System.out.println("Right:" + Arrays.toString(right));` immediately after the for loop I am able to see that ,right array is holding the correct values.